# How to get d3 instance from d3 selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, selection

I have a method that gets a d3 selection as an argument:

```
function foo(selection){

}
```

Inside that function I need the d3 instance. Instead of passing the d3 instance as an extra argument I would like to get it from the selection. Is that possible?

```
function foo(selection){
    var d3 = selection.getD3();
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    d3.select(element);
}
```

*Edit*

The methods provided by the selection do not include something like "getD3":

```
append
attr
call
classed
clone
constructor
data
datum
dispatch
each
empty
enter
exit
filter
html
insert
interrupt
lower
merge
node
nodes
on
order
property
raise
remove
select
selectAll
size
sort
style
text
transition
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Under what circumstances is this function called? Why can't you just refer to `d3` in that function? This seems like a very special use case; I cannot conceive of a single instance this would have caused any problems in my code. But, you'll never know...

Comment: On top of what was said in the comment above, if you know you're passing a D3 selection why would you need this? I mean, you could use `instanceof d3.selection` to test, but I don't see the point since you already know that!

Answer (score -1):

You can add a reference to `d3` by adding it to the `selection` object

```
var mySelection = d3.selectAll('your_selection_criteria');

mySelection.d3_reference = d3;  //mySelection is a JSON object, so
                                // you can attach anything to it

foo(mySelection);


function foo(selection) {
    var myD3 = selection.d3_reference;
    // now myD3 is d3
}
```

Comment: This work around works of course. :) Since d3 does not seem to support this natively, I decided to pass the d3 instance explicitly.

Comment: @downvoter It would be helpful if you left a comment explaining why you choose to downvote this answer